# How to install 64 Bit snort on 64 Bit openSUSE 13.1?

Tags: opensuse, 64bit, snort

My question is simple: I would like to install 64 Bit snort on my 64 Bit openSUSE 13.1.
There is an unstable package available here:http://software.opensuse.org/package/snort

I got everything but where can I get libpcre.so.0(64bit) that is missing on my system?

The same question was on official openSUSE forum, but without any answer. It would be useful if someone can help me.

Answer (score 0):

Use the distribution's tools to install the package and it's dependencies. But I'd strongly advise against installing unstable/non-official packages, unless you know exactly what you are doing, and have very strong reasons for needing that package. Before considering such, check if the needed features have been backported/included in the official package.

Comment: I have checked this. There´s no stable pacakge available that  contains snort in 64 bit. I think I should compile the perl regex lib for myself, shouldn´t I?